# Eclipse - Setting .classpath file for existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath, weka

I have a java project.  The working folder from someone else's Eclipse project (It was a Repast Simphony project I think).

In my eclipse I created a new Java project and told it to use the existing code.  So it seems to have brought in all the code.

However after loading the project I get this error:

```
Project 'My Project' is missing required Java project: 'Weka 3-7'
```

It has a .classpath file with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Weka-3-7"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

What I've tried so far:

I installed Weka 3-7.  Then I updated the .classpath file to say the following and reloaded the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="C|/Program Files/Weka-3-7"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

But now I get the error message:

```
Project 'My Project' is missing required source folder: 'C|/Program Files/Weka-3-7'
```

Please help.  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use the context menu: My Project::(right mouse click)::Build Path::Configure Build path. This gives you the option to add/remove projects, Jars, source folders etc., what erver you need to provide those classes that your project references. You *can* get the same effect by hacking the `.classpath` manually, but you have to know *very* well what you're doing. Always use the frontend unless it absolutely can't do what you need.

Comment: Thanks.  Any ideas what settings I'd use in the Configure build path dialog to replicate what the .classpath was originally doing?  I tried the "link source" option but now I'm getting all kinds of errors of the nature: "ArffReader cannot be resolved to a type", etc.

Comment: The `kind="src"` entries in the `.classpath` are created by putting stuff into the "Source" or "Projects" tabs of the Java Build Path wizard, son you can't reproduce them until you actually *have* the corresponding Java project registered in your workspace (or have the Java sources within your own project).

Comment: +1 for "My Project > (right mouse click) > `Build Path` > `Configure Build path`" -- which corresponds exactly (at least in the order of items) to the lines in `.classpath`.